# $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) vs. armv6, armv7/armv7s vs. i386

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an iPhone App which should run on armv7 as well as armv6. For debugging the App should run in the simulator too.

The Standard in Xcode 4.2 is this:

armv7 (`$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`)

It is not clear to me what `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` stands for and if I should use the two:

1. $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
2. armv6

Or all three like this

1. armv6
2. armv7
3. i386

What is the best option for this in my case? And how does `Architectures` work with `Valid Architectures`

Comment: I can now compile it for armv6 when using `armv6` and `armv7` as `architecture` (without `i386`). So currently I am not using the `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`

Comment: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) is defined in the Xcode default template, which you can't modify, although you could override it by making your own configuration. It used to be defined as "armv6 arv7" but they changed it in 4.2 to just "armv7". I was able to restore the old behaviour by just using your first technique, but only on targets that use the iOS SDK (you have to click the little "(+)" button in the build settings to add lines for the SDK iOS vs simulator, and only change it for iOS).

Comment: Does anyone know which iOS devices require armv6? Is it mainly just the iPod Touch 3G as mentioned in the comment below?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To run in the simulator you don't have to do anything.

You can leave the `Valid Architectures` setting at `armv6 armv7`, because, according to the docs:

> During the build, this list is intersected with the value of ARCHS
>   build setting

To support armv6 and armv7, set the architectures to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) armv6`, $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) currently expands to armv7.

Also check if there is a "Required device capabilities" = `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` setting in your plist file, as Xcode will add armv7 for new projects there.

Comment: that makes complete sense. For some reason - still unknown - Xcode started complaining with [BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv6, VALID_ARCHS=i386). That was only for the simulator build. Adding i386 to the list of valid architectures caused a different error "gcc exit code 255". So, your answer is bang on. I put in $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) that covers the simulator and armv7, and added another line armv6 specifically for iPod Touch 3G 8GB.

Comment: I had the exact same issue as @MaxMacLeod and this fixed it - ARCHS was set to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) but VALID_ARCHS to armv7. Changing both to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) works - though I don't really understand how i386 is a valid target when it isn't listed!

Comment: @k1th nice answer.. a reference wouldn't hurt though.. i would like to know where you figured out what ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT means (gave you a +1 anyways :)

Comment: There is a plist:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/iPhoneOSArchitectures.xcspec

Answer (score 8):

**Update with Xcode 4.5**: Apple added the new architecture `armv7s`, which adds optimisations for the new hardware of the iPhone 5.

Since I could not test our app on the new iPhone5, I removed this architecture from our app by changing the supported architecture from `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` (which means `armv7` + `armv7s`) to only `armv7`.

If you want or have to support the older iPhone 3G you also need to addd `armv6`.

You need to do this for both **Architectures** and **Valid Architectures**.